# Over 98% connections in pg_stat_activity are idle and running SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, amazon-rds, c3p0

Similar question: [Lot of SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL queries in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146741/lot-of-show-transaction-isolation-level-queries-in-postgres)

I did look above questions and did lots of research, still confused.

My service database is in PostgreSQL AWS RDS, and I use C3P0 for connection pooling. However i found almost all of the connections in `pg_stat_activity` are running either `SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` or `SELECT 1`. All of these connections are `idle`.

My concern is that with the service TPS stays the same, say 10 TPS, the number of connections in database keeps growing. 
Even if all these connections are `idle`, seems like every time there's a client hit the service database, there's a new connection being created and stay forever. 
Also even if the TPS trends down, the number of connection still keeps growing, just little be slower.

Can anybody share some insight through this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: These connections are not *running* the commands, the statements are just the last statements that ran on these connections before they turned idle. You have a connection leak in your connection pool - make sure you return connections to the pool when you are done.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe those connections have very recent query_start date, and it keeps changing everytime I do a select. I have closed all the connection in a finally block, is there anything else I should do?

Comment: Are you using a connection pooler or any kind?