# How to find connection leaks on PostgreSQL cloud sql

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I’m using Postgres provisioned by Google Cloud SQL, 
Recently we see the number of connections to increase by a lot.

Had to raise the limit from 200 to 500, then to 1000. In Google Cloud console Postgres reports 800 currenct connections.

However I have no idea where these connections come from. We have one app engine service, with not a lot of traffic at the moment accessing it, another application hosted on kubernetes. And a dozen or so batch jobs that connect to it. Clearly there must be some connection leakage somewhere.

Is there any way I can see from where these connections originate ?

All applications connecting to it are Java based at the moment.
They use the HikariCP connection pool. I’m considering changing the “test query”upon connection to insert a record in a log table. Hence I could perhaps find out from where the connections originate.

But are there better ways available?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Consider monitoring connection activity with [pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW), i.e: `SELECT * from pg_stat_activity;`.

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/diagnose-issues#determining_how_connections_are_being_initiated):

> Connections that show an IP address, such as 1.2.3.4, are connecting using IP. Connections with cloudsqlproxy~1.2.3.4 are using the Cloud SQL Proxy, or else they originated from App Engine. Connections from localhost are usually to a First Generation instance from App Engine, although that path is also used by some internal Cloud SQL processes.

Also, take a look at the [best practices for managing database connections](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/manage-connections) that contain information on opening and closing connections, connection count, or on how to set a connection duration in the Java programming language.

Comment: When I run this query I see that 95% of all connections have this in their query field:

SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL

Comment: This is caused by HikariCP connection pool. Possibly when calling the [getTransactionIsolation()](https://static.javadoc.io/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/2.6.3/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.html#getTransactionIsolation--) method. I recommend checking [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49585/getting-multiple-queries-with-show-transaction-isolation-level-in-pg-activity/168979) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146741/lot-of-show-transaction-isolation-level-queries-in-postgres) posts for more info.